# Error while calculating a route: RoutingError.forbidden

Tags: flutter, dart, navigation, maps, here-api

I face this message when I try to run one of HERE Maps SDK examples with Flutter.

**Navigation Quick start app.**

I face this massage:

flutter: Error while calculating a route: RoutingError.forbidden

I use the latest version of HERE SDK 4.12.0.0

framework info:

Flutter 3.1.0-0.0.pre.1489 •

Tools • Dart 2.18.0 (build 2.18.0-250.0.dev) • DevTools 2.15.0

Comment: Could you please try to run the any of below example.

https://github.com/heremaps/here-sdk-examples/tree/master/examples/latest/navigate/flutter

Answer (score 1):

According to the HERE SDK [release notes](https://developer.here.com/documentation/flutter-sdk-navigate), Flutter 3.x is not yet supported due to a [known issue with platform views](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/103630).

Consider to downgrade your Flutter version to the latest supported version as indicated in the [user guide](https://developer.here.com/documentation/flutter-sdk-navigate).